# Pass image from Python to a MATLAB function

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use a MATLAB function in Python using the MATLAB Python engine. The MATLAB function is for processing an image. Here is my code:

```
import matlab.engine
import os
from PIL import Image

img_rows, img_cols = 256, 256
img_channels = 1

path0 = r'D:\NEW PICS\non_stressed'
path2 = r'D:\empty2'

listing = os.listdir(path0) 
num_samples=size(listing)
print (num_samples)
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

for file in listing:
    im = Image.open(path0 + '\\' + file)   
    img = im.resize((img_rows,img_cols))
    gray = img.convert('L')

    #gray: This is the image I want to pass from Python to MATLAB
    reg = eng.LBP(gray)   
    reg.save(path2 +'\\' +  file, "JPEG")
```

But it gives me this error:

> TypeError: unsupported Python data type: `PIL.Image.Image`

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the MATLAB documentation on how to [Pass Data to MATLAB from Python](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pass-data-to-matlab-from-python.html), only a certain number of types are supported. This includes scalar data types, such as `int`, `float` and more, as well as (partly) `dict`. Further, `list`, `set`, and `tuple` are automatically converted to MATLAB cell arrays.

But: `array.array`, and any `module.type` objects are *not* supported. This includes `PIL.Image.Image`, like in your case. You will have to convert the image to a supported datatype before passing it to MATLAB.

For arrays, MATLAB recommends to use their special [MATLAB Array type](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-arrays-as-python-variables.html) for Python. You can convert the PIL Image to e.g. a `uint8` MATLAB Array with

```
from PIL import Image
import matlab.engine

image = Image.new('RGB', (1024, 1280))
image_mat = matlab.uint8(list(image.getdata()))
image_mat.reshape((image.size[0], image.size[1], 3))
```

The final `reshape` command is required because PIL's `getdata()` function returns a flattened list of pixel values, so the image width and height are lost. Now, you can call any MATLAB function on the `image_mat` array.

Comment: hey! thanks :) the code worked. But the output of matlab function can not be saved in a folder as its data type is double. so how can we convert it back to python data type?